# OpenCV traincascade XML file error

Tags: python, xml, opencv

Not quite sure where I'm going wrong - I'm trying to train OpenCV for object detection with +/- images that I've taken myself.  All the steps work ok, but ultimately my Python script won't read my XML cascade file (but will load one of the built-in face detection files).

For what it's worth, I'm on Mac Lion running Python 2.7.3.

My process:

1. Create a collection file with bounding boxes on the positive images
2. Create a list of negative images
3. Use `opencv_createsamples` using the following command: `opencv_createsamples -info collection.txt -bg negativeImages.txt -vec positiveVectorFile.vec -num 20 -w 32 -h 24`
4. Check vector file: images are a bit squished but look ok
5. Run `traincascade` program using the following command: `opencv_traincascade -data directoryToStoreFiles -vec positiveVectorFile.vec -bg negativeImageList.txt -numPos 16 -numNeg 20 -numStages 5 -mem 1000 -maxHitRate 0.95 -w 32 -h 24`

Then I run the following Python script (which works with the usual face-detection XML):

```
import cv
img = cv.LoadImage("test.jpg", 0)

# load detection file (various files for different views and uses)
cascade = cv.Load("cascade.xml")        # doesn't work
#cascade = cv.Load("frontalface.xml")   # works

# detect faces, return as list
detected = cv.HaarDetectObjects(img, cascade, cv.CreateMemStorage())

# iterate detected objects, drawing a rectangle around each
for (x,y, w,h), n in detected:
    cv.Rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), 255)

# create a window to display the results
windowTitle = "Test Cascade"
cv.NamedWindow(windowTitle, cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

# display tested image until the escape key is pressed
while True:
    cv.ShowImage(windowTitle, img)

    # watch for escape key (ASCII 20)
    key = cv.WaitKey(20)
    if key == 27:

        # save the image to file is specified
        if saveIt == True:
            cv.SaveImage("detected.png", img)

        # ... and quit
        exit()
```

The result is the error:
`cv2.error: The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)`

I've uploaded the cascade file here: http://pastebin.com/w7uRjyN7.  Not sure if it's my cascade file, some other problem along the way, or something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it appears that cyberdecker's suggestion was one of a few problems: that cv2 has entirely different commands for *everything* and is required when using `opencv_traincascade`.  My code, which now works (though my cascade doesn't quite yet):

```
#import library - MUST use cv2 if using opencv_traincascade
import cv2

# rectangle color and stroke
color = (0,0,255)       # reverse of RGB (B,G,R) - weird
strokeWeight = 1        # thickness of outline

# set window name
windowName = "Object Detection"

# load an image to search for faces
img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")

# load detection file (various files for different views and uses)
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("cascade.xml")

# preprocessing, as suggested by: http://www.bytefish.de/wiki/opencv/object_detection
# img_copy = cv2.resize(img, (img.shape[1]/2, img.shape[0]/2))
# gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_copy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# gray = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)

# detect objects, return as list
rects = cascade.detectMultiScale(img)

# display until escape key is hit
while True:

    # get a list of rectangles
    for x,y, width,height in rects:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+width, y+height), color, strokeWeight)

    # display!
    cv2.imshow(windowName, img)

    # escape key (ASCII 27) closes window
    if cv2.waitKey(20) == 27:
        break

# if esc key is hit, quit!
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, because I don't work with python-opencv, only with C++ part. Are you sure that you are using the correct wrapper function for detectMultiScale instead of the old C cvHaarDetect? Because your cascade was trained with traincascade, which generates cascades that only works with the function CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale. It will not work with cvHaarDetect.

I think that the function you need to use in python is `cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale`, take a look on the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale).

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the suggestion (it was something I thought might cause an issue).  The error actually seems to come from the cv.Load - thrown before it could give an error on the CascadeClassifier.

Comment: EDIT: one step closer, it appears cv2 requires cascades to be loaded as `cv2.CascadeClassifier("filename.xml")`

Comment: Yes, when you switch to cv2 and traincascade, it changes a lot on the functions. About your cascade, the training has terminated correctly? You said that your code runs now, nice! Did you tested with some opencv cascade to be sure that it loaded successfully the cascade?

Comment: Yes!  The code works with all cv2 functions and (finally) my cascade.  The confusion has mostly come from lots of not great and old tutorials online.  The cv2/traincascade question was just one of many that I think are mostly resolved.

For example: what appears to be a "false leaf rate" error is actually the program saying "everything is good, we're done!"

Thanks for getting me on the right track!